# sql for paging notice board in jsp

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jsp, oracle11g

I'm trying to make a notice board and before apply paging function it showed posts well.

but after i applied paging fuction it shows only one post and paging function shows pages well.

so i think this is a sql problem. 
when i try to show count it shows 1. even i tried with this shows 1.

```
sql = "select * from mvc_board ";
```

this is my sql

```
 String sql = "SELECT ROWNUM, bId, bName, bTitle, bContent," +
               "bDate, bHit, bGroup, bStep, bIndent " +
               "from(select * from mvc_board order by bGroup DESC , bStep asc)";
```

i tried to make mine from this sql. but couldn't understand.

```
sql = "select *, (select u_name from user where idx = writer_fk) writer, (select idx from answer where idx = answer_fk) answer from board order by idx desc limit "+startRow+", "+endRow;
```

ref.  http://queserasera.tistory.com/14

this is DAO

```
  public ArrayList<BDto> getBoardList(int startRow, int endRow, String keyField, String keyWord) {
        ArrayList<BDto> dtos = new ArrayList<BDto>();
        Connection connection = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        String sql = "SELECT ROWNUM, bId, bName, bTitle, bContent," +
               "bDate, bHit, bGroup, bStep, bIndent " +
               "from(select * from mvc_board order by bGroup DESC , bStep asc)";
       System.out.println(sql);
         try{
            if(keyWord != null && !keyWord.equals("") && !keyWord.equals("null")) {
                sql += " WHERE " + keyField.trim() +" LIKE '%"+keyWord.trim()+"%'";
            }


           connection =  dataSource.getConnection();

           //특정행부터  레코드를 가져오기 위해서 옵션 설정
           preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

           while(resultSet.next()){

             int count=0;

                int ROWNUM = resultSet.getInt("ROWNUM");
                int bId = resultSet.getInt("bId");
                String bName = resultSet.getString("bName");
                String bTitle = resultSet.getString("bTitle");
                String bContent = resultSet.getString("bContent");
                Timestamp bDate = resultSet.getTimestamp("bDate");
                int bHit = resultSet.getInt("bHit");
                int bGroup = resultSet.getInt("bGroup");
                int bStep = resultSet.getInt("bStep");
                int bIndent = resultSet.getInt("bIndent");

                BDto dto = new BDto(ROWNUM, bId, bName, bTitle, bContent, bDate, bHit, bGroup, bStep, bIndent);
                dtos.add(dto);

                  count++;
                  System.out.println(count);
             //while문끝

           }//if문끝


        }catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println(e+"=> getBoardList fail");
       }finally {
            try {
                if(resultSet != null) resultSet.close();
                if(preparedStatement != null) preparedStatement.close();
                if(connection != null) connection.close();
            } catch (Exception e2) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

       return dtos;
   }
```

=============added sql on sql developer==================================

```
select rn, bId, bName, bTitle, bContent, bDate, bHit, bGroup, bStep, bIndent 
from ( select b.*, row_number() over (order by bGroup DESC, bStep asc) rn
from mvc_board b %s ) 
where rn between 1 and 10
order by rn;
```

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using?

Comment: @MickMnemonic 11g!

Comment: Please share the code for `getTotalRecord()`

Comment: @MickMnemonic I added ! thanks!

Comment: By the way, how do you know `mvc_board` has more than one rows?

Comment: @MickMnemonic because i have another notice board which hasn't paging function and it works well..

Comment: Okay. The main problem is in `getBoardList()`: the `if (resultSet.next())` should be `while (resultSet.next())` instead. I'll write an answer to cover the paging part, as well.

Comment: @MickMnemonic ohhh it works!!!! thanks you so much!!!! would you also check sql part for paging? now paging is left! it shows pages well, but still shows all posts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem in your `getBoardList()` method was the usage of `if (resultSet.next())` instead of `while (resultSet.next())` when iterating through the result set; that caused the code to only ever return a single DTO.

There are other things you should also consider. For example, starting from Java 7, it's preferrable to use the [try-with resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) instead of traditional `try-finally` for JDBC resource handling.

An important thing to note is that injecting field names like `keyField` from the UI is a really bad practice because it makes the query vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).
You should at least create a static whitelist of allowed field names to sanitize the input, if you cannot use static WHERE conditions.

Finally, paging queries in Oracle 11g are traditionally done with an inline view that uses the [`row_number` analytic function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm). Note that row-numbering starts from 1. Starting from Oracle 12c, [the row-limiting clause](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1) can be used and the inline view is no longer needed.

An example implementation that considers the above points could look like the following:

```
 public List<BDto> getBoardList(int startRow, int endRow, String keyField, String keyWord) {

    List<BDto> dtos = new ArrayList<BDto>();

    // the %s in the template will be replaced with a 
    // WHERE condition when a keyword is present
    final String sqlTemplate = "select rn, bId, bName, bTitle, "
            + "bContent, bDate, bHit, bGroup, bStep, bIndent "
            + "from ( "
            + "     select b.*, row_number() over (order by bGroup DESC, bStep asc) rn" 
            + "    from mvc_board b %s "
            + "    ) "
            + "    where rn between ? and ? "
            + "order by rn";

    boolean whereCondition = false;

    String sql = null;

    if (keyWord != null && !keyWord.equals("") && !keyWord.equals("null")) {
        sql = String.format(sqlTemplate, 
                   " WHERE " + keyField.trim() + " LIKE '%' || ? || '%'");
        whereCondition = true;
    } else {
        sql = String.format(sqlTemplate, "");
    }

    System.out.println(sql);

    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) {

        int parameterIndex = 1;

        if (whereCondition) {
            preparedStatement.setString(parameterIndex++, keyWord);
        }
        preparedStatement.setInt(parameterIndex++, startRow);
        preparedStatement.setInt(parameterIndex, endRow);

        try (ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery()) {

            int count = 0;

            while (resultSet.next()) {

                int ROWNUM = resultSet.getInt("rn");
                int bId = resultSet.getInt("bId");
                String bName = resultSet.getString("bName");
                String bTitle = resultSet.getString("bTitle");
                String bContent = resultSet.getString("bContent");
                Timestamp bDate = resultSet.getTimestamp("bDate");
                int bHit = resultSet.getInt("bHit");
                int bGroup = resultSet.getInt("bGroup");
                int bStep = resultSet.getInt("bStep");
                int bIndent = resultSet.getInt("bIndent");

                dtos.add(new BDto(ROWNUM, bId, bName, bTitle, 
                        bContent, bDate, bHit, bGroup, bStep, bIndent));

                count++;
            }
            System.out.println(count);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e + "=> getBoardList fail");
    }

    return dtos;
}
```

Comment: it works well! thank you a lot! i find out one more ploblem.. when i search specific word,  it shows pages and posts well. but when i go  to page 2 or next page  it doesn't applied seaching keyword. I don't know how can i transfer keyWord&keyField..! i editted list.jsp could you check? thanks!

Comment: I posted  new subject about that! Would you check this one too?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52847297/jsp-paging-problem-when-i-go-to-next-page-searching-keyword-doesnt-apply

Comment: Hi, your code worked very well, but when i try on sql developer it didn't work :( 
i added on my post below

Comment: That's because the Java code replaces the `%s` part with a WHERE condition if a keyword is present (see the block inside `if (keyWord != null...)`).

Answer (score 1):

In the example you gave us the paging is added by the `limit` clause, but `ORACLE`has it's own syntax for these. Try:

```
 String sql = "SELECT rown, bId, bName, bTitle, bContent," +
              "bDate, bHit, bGroup, bStep, bIndent " +
              "from(select rownum rown, mvc_board.* from mvc_board order by bGroup DESC , bStep asc) " +
              "WHERE rown between ? and ? ";
```

Bind `startRow` and `endRow` before executing the query:

```
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setInt(1,startRow);
preparedStatement.setInt(2,endRow);
resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Change the `WHERE` to `AND`:

```
sql +=" and " + keyField.trim()+" LIKE '%"+keyWord.trim()+"%'" ;
```

And finally change the `if(resultSet.next()){` back to a `while` loop to get more then one row as result.

Comment: with that sql i cant understand. cuz i don't know what  u_name,  writer_fk, writer, answer_fk, answer ..  so now im using String sql = "SELECT ROWNUM, bId, bName, bTitle, bContent," +
               "bDate, bHit, bGroup, bStep, bIndent " +
               "from(select * from mvc_board order by bGroup DESC , bStep asc)";

Comment: also i tried to do just < sql = "select * from mvc_board ";> which is still shows 1post on jsp. so i added list.jsp and BListCommand.java !

Comment: OP is using Oracle 11g, where the [row-limiting clause](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1) isn't yet available.