# jsp paging problem when i go to next page searching keyword doesn't apply

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jsp

when i search specific word only first page is classified. it shows pages and posts well on first page.

but when i go to page 2 or next page, seaching keyword doesn't apply on 
is this address problem?

i guess this is sql or Paging.java problem  because when i print log of page at BDAO it shows page well which i clicked.

also I don't know how can i transfer keyWord &keyField for that..!

I use oracle DB.

```
  <% 
String keyWord = (String)request.getParameter("keyWord");
String keyField = (String)request.getParameter("keyField");
%>
<script>

    function searchCheck(frm){
        //검색
        if(frm.keyWord.value ==""){
            alert("검색 단어를 입력하세요.");
            frm.keyWord.focus();
            return;
        }
        frm.submit();      
    }

    function PageMove(page){
         var keyWord = '<%=keyWord%>'
         var keyField = '<%=keyField%>'
         console.log(keyWord);
         if(keyWord !=''){
        location.href = "list.do?page="+page+"&keyWord=" + keyWord + "&keyField=" + keyField;
         }
         location.href = "list.do?page="+page;
      }
</script>
</head>
<body>  

    <table width="800" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>번호</td>
            <td>이름</td>
            <td>제목</td>
            <td>날짜</td>
            <td>히트</td>
        </tr>
        <c:forEach items="${list}" var="dto">
        <tr>
            <td>${dto.bId}</td>
            <td>${dto.bName}</td>
            <td>
                <c:forEach begin="1" end="${dto.bIndent}">-</c:forEach>
                <a href="content_view.do?bId=${dto.bId}">${dto.bTitle}</a></td>
            <td>${dto.bDate}</td>
            <td>${dto.bHit}</td>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
                <form action="list.do" method="post" name="search">
                <select name="keyField">
                    <option value="bTitle">글 제목</option>
                    <option value="bContent">글 내용</option>
                    <option value="bName">작성자</option>
                </select>
                <input type="text" name="keyWord">
                <input type="button" value="검색" onclick="searchCheck(form)">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td colspan="5"> <a href="write_view.do">글작성</a> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="toolbar-bottom">
  <div class="toolbar mt-lg">
    <div class="sorter">
      <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="javascript:PageMove(${paging.firstPageNo})">맨앞으로</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:PageMove(${paging.prevPageNo})">앞으로</a></li>
              <c:forEach var="i" begin="${paging.startPageNo}" end="${paging.endPageNo}" step="1">
                  <c:choose>
                      <c:when test="${i eq paging.pageNo}">
                <li class="active"><a href="javascript:PageMove(${i})">${i}</a></li>
                      </c:when>
                      <c:otherwise>
                        <li><a href="javascript:PageMove(${i})">${i}</a></li>
                      </c:otherwise>
                  </c:choose>
              </c:forEach>
        <li><a href="javascript:PageMove(${paging.nextPageNo})">뒤로</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:PageMove(${paging.finalPageNo})">맨뒤로</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add them to your `request` object in your servlet

Comment: @ScaryWombat I added BListCommand.java. and i think in BListCommand.java. i did?

Comment: Do you expose the `bTitle` property from the DTO, i.e. is there a `getBTitle()` method in the class?

Comment: @MickMnemonic i added ' '  and it works!! but still when i search specific word only first page is classified. next page  doesn't apply on

Comment: So, did you try to get the keyfield/word values from the page elements in `PageMove()` with `document.getElementById(...)` as I suggested?

Comment: with your suggestion it shows [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null] so i couldn't move to next page :( do i need to set keyWord&keyField somewhere?  i already did in BListCommand.java tho...

Comment: It's unclear to me what's showing on the page and when. Are the keyfield dropdown and the keyword input showing all the time? If not, then naturally you cannot access the elements with JavaScript. You should make sure that the filter parameters carry over between all requests.

Comment: @MickMnemonic when i get data from <%request.getParameter("keyWord"); %>it shows data well, but i can't transter to javascript code . with document.getElementById("keyWord").value; has an error

Comment: Please edit the question with all the code you're currently using (e.g. `PageMove()` doesn't currently contain `getElementById(...)`). Do you get the error on all pages or only after going to the next page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never seem to be passing the keyword or keyfield when you call `pageMove()`. You might as well look up their values inside the function instead of having them as parameters:

```
function PageMove(page){
    var keyWord = document.getElementById("keyWord").value;
    var keyField = document.getElementById("keyField").value;
    location.href = "list.do?page=" + page + "&keyWord=" + keyWord + "&keyField=" + keyField;
}
```

Comment: i try to fixt it with your code, but occurs error "Uncaught ReferenceError: bTitle is not defined" , it doesn't go to next page when i search specific word! also can't read document.getElementById("keyWord").value;

Comment: Please don't add code in comments; edit the question instead to include this information. Your question didn't mention the `Uncaught ReferenceError` problem. Have you seen that all the time? Please include all relevant information about the problems you're experiencing directly in the question.

Comment: sorry ! i editted code! and thanks for letting me know the rules!

Comment: I finished!! fixed and it works!  I set local address not with javascript!